# Install openjdk-11-jdk 32bit on Ubuntu 20.04 64bit

Tags: 20.04, openjdk

I have installed openjdk-11 64 bit, but I need to install 32bit version

```
$ lsb_release -a
 No LSB modules are available.
 Distributor ID: Ubuntu
 Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
 Release:        20.04
 Codename:       focal
$ java -version
 openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
$ update-java-alternatives --list
 java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

I tried to run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk:i386
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to locate package openjdk-11-jdk:i386
```

How can install it?

Comment: From this info it is not saying it can not install it. It is saying it can not find it. Where do you expect this app to be found?

Comment: Does `apt-cache search default-jdk:i386` find something. you are aware you have to add i386 architecture.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu, or a Ubuntu-based system as your `lsb_release -a` details do **not** match an upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 system, but instead match a system based on an older Ubuntu 20.04.2 system. Your details match a system prior to [late August-2021](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/) which is not what an [updated system will report](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/) & note the ISO release dates in my links are week+ behind when installed systems got those updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely don't have the `i386` architecture enabled. Do the following:

```bash
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk:i386
```